# i-- and i = i-1 not evaluating the same

Tags: javascript, evaluation

I thought that `i--` is a shorthand for `i = i - 1`, but I discovered that both evaluate different:

```js
var i = 1;
while (i = i - 1) {…}
```

In this case, `i` is `0`, which evaluates to `false`. This works as expected.

```js
var i = 1;
while (i--) {…}
```

`i` should be `0` and evaluate to `false`, but it does not. It evaluates to `true`. Is this a bug, or is there a reason for it?

Comment: `--i` is the relevant one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `i--` will be evaluated only after the loop condition is evaluated but *before* the statements within the loop. This is the decrement postfix operator. That means that initially the evaluation of the condition in the loop condition would be `true`. This will fire the execution of the statements in the loop's body. When the statements in the loop's body will be executed, since the `i` had be decremented by one, it would be equal to 0. Hence the evaluation of the loop condition would be `false` and the statements in the loop's body will not be executed again.

Comment: *"The i-- will be evaluated only after a first loop will be executed."* - No, `i` will be decremented after the loop condition is evaluated but *before* the statements within the loop.

Comment: that means that `while(i--) {…}` is essentially the same as `while (i) {i-=1;}`?

Comment: @Afterlame - `while(i--){}` isn't quite the same as `while(i) {i-=1;}`, because if `i` was 0 before the while statement then after the former it would be -1 even though the body of the loop didn't run; after the latter `i` would still be 0.

Comment: @nnnnnn This means `i--` will be executed when it is checked for the while loop, regardless if the body of the loop will actually run?

Comment: Yes. First the original value of `i` is used to decide whether to execute the loop, then the value of `i` is changed, then (possibly) the loop body will execute.

Answer (score 4):

When you do `i--`, the value of `i` is used and *then* decremented. But in case of a prefix `--1` operator it is different, as in, it will be decremented and *then* used.

```
var i = j = 1;
console.log(i--); // still 1
console.log(i); // now 0
console.log(--j) // 0
console.log(j); // again 0
```

### Why explain the above?

To show you what's going on actually behind when you use pre-fix and post-fix operators, though it is not *mainly* concerned with the question, but I thought it would be better to know.

### Now the actual answer

What `i = i - 1` does is it evaluates as soon as the code is encountered, so `i` is actually `0`, you can say it acts similar to pre-fix decrement operator, in this case, but `i--` is still `1` when the *condition* used in `while` is evaluated for the first time and then when the second time the `while` *condition* is checked, it is `0`, which is *falsey* and hence the loop ends.

Comment: Thanks for the example and the `--j` operator. I did not know that this one exists.

Comment: @Afterlame glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `--i`as the pre-decrement operator.

See the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Decrement)

Comment: Removed reference to PHP docs (I didn't read the question). Added reference to JavaScript docs.

Answer (score -1):

`i--` is not the same as `i=i-1`, when used in a loop.

`i--` will be evaluated *after* the condition, but before the loop contents are run, whereas `i=i-1` will be evaluated *before* the condition, so will evaluate to false.

I guess in that respect `--i` is more similar to `i=i-1`, as it is also evaluated prior to the condition.

You can think of

```
while (i--) {...}
```

As being equivalent to

```
while (i = i - 1, i + 1) {...}
```

Comment: Your "equivalent" operation isn't really equivalent. With `i--` the value *will* be decremented before the body of the loop runs (but after the loop condition is evaluated).

Comment: I know, just fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the updated version is still not equivalent, because `while(i--)` evaluates the condition before changing `i`, but your `do/while` evaluates the condition *after* changing `i`.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, but the script will display exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, but the new version is only equivalent if `i` is not 0 before reaching the while statement. I'm not sure if there is a simple, tidy way to rewrite the `while(i--)` given that it will always decrement i even if the loop body isn't run. Easier to just remember that's how it works and use `--i` instead where appropriate. (Again, sorry - I'm not *trying* to be annoying.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Why are the two code blocks not "equivalent"?

Comment: Well, as per my previous comment (three years ago?), they are equivalent _if_ `i` is not `0` before reaching the `while`. But if `i` is `0` then neither will run the loop body but the first will change the value of `i` and the second won't. (In the question, we see that `i` is not `0`, but in the answer we don't, and more generally if applying this code to unknown situations we can't be sure.)